# Need explanation for 'under the hood' of get and set in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, get, set

Given the code below even though the name of the parameter is on the beginning firstName, after setting it with setter and looking at the properties of an object it becomes _firstName. I am coming from a Java development background and this seems unlogical to me. Can somebody explain, please?

```
class Person {
constructor(firstName, DOB, sport) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.sport = sport;
    }   
get firstName() {  
        return this._firstName;
    }
set firstName(firstName) {
        this._firstName = firstName;   
    }
}

const person1 = new Person('Marko', '2002', 'tennis');`
```

Object after `person1.firstName = 'Luka';`

```
(Person {_firstName: 'Luka', DOB: '1256', _sport: 'tennis'}
DOB: "1256"
_firstName: "Luka"
_sport: "tennis"
DO: undefined
firstName: (...)
sport: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Object)
```

I tried `person1.firstName = 'Luka';` and was expecting object field to stay firstName but it became _firstName (with underline). I see that I am making this change in this line `this._firstName = firstName;` but I do not understand how can variable name be overriden

Answer (score 1):

`this.firstName` is a **method** setting the **property** `this._firstName`.

Calling the setter method `this.firstName = "Marko"` works similar to calling a standard method like `this.firstName("Marko")`. Since you're using the method in your constructor it "looks like" you're setting the property `this.firstName` when you're actually using the method `this.firstName` to set the property `this._firstName`.

Modifying `this.firstName` method helps understand this:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, DOB, sport) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.DOB = DOB;
        this.sport = sport;
    }   
get firstName() {  
        return this._firstName;
    }
set firstName(firstName) {
        //this will output on the console whenever the method is being used
        console.log("setter method used");
        this._firstName = firstName;   
    }
}
const person1 = new Person('Marko', '2002', 'tennis');
```

You should see on the console that the setter method was used once. Now try changing the first line of your constructor to `this._firstName = firstName;`

Comment: I am explaining that in my post. Read my first sentence: `this.firstName` is a **method** setting the **property** `this._firstName`

Comment: @Teemu — It's defined by the method they wrote which says `this._firstName = firstName;` … like Mattias said, and repeated in their previous comment.

Comment: @Teemu — What shadowing? There's no shadowing.

Comment: Magic? The first call of the setter function defines the property (adds it to the class) and sets its value. Further calls to the function would change that value.

Shadowing? I don't see a problem here. There are no two variables/properties/functions/methods of the same name.

Comment: @Teemu — Why *should* anything be shadowed? As Matthias said, there's no two things which have the same name.

Comment: @Teemu — The methods that are called.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, I totally forgot that read-only properties in the prototype can't be shadowed, and getters/setters are read-only by default. My bad, I'll remove the comments.